# Problem with RavenDB 'Hello World' tutorial

Tags: ravendb

I am going through the RavenDB tutorial on the RavenDb.net website.
It was going fine until I got to the code block for creating an index.
This code segment is direct from RavenDB.Net website.

```
store.DatabaseCommands.PutIndex("OrdersContainingProduct", new IndexDefinition<Order>
{
    Map = orders => from order in orders
                    from line in order.OrderLines
                    select new { line.ProductId }
});
```

I get an error on compile:  "The non-generic type 'Raven.Database.Indexing.IndexDefinition' cannot be used with type arguments."

If **IndexDefinition** is non-generic, why is it used as generic in the sample code?  Where is the disconnect?

Thank you for your time
Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on your using statements you may be referencing the wrong IndexDefinition class (from another Raven assembly). Try adding this to the beginning of your file:

```
using Raven.Client.Indexes;
```

You might need to remove other using statements as well. I guess this is one reason why Microsoft recommends using unique names for classes even in the presence of namespaces.

Comment: Thanks that was it.  I don't know how I missed that one.  That was about the only using directive that I did not include.

Comment: This is a direct result of a pervasive problem with code tutorials, examples, and explanations everywhere on the net.  Why do people rarely include the 'using' directives?

Comment: That's a good point, should I start doing that in my examples?

Comment: I am not sure why, this answer stands invalid as i dont see generic version of IndexDefinition in RavenDB code repository

Comment: This isn't fixing the problem (at least not for the 360 build!)